# How to find the number of trees of a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

What is the process of finding the number of trees of a graph?

Q: Amongst all trees with 10 vertices {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} consider those which have a vertex of degree 8. What is the number of such trees? Justify your answer.

Comment: It's not "the number of trees of a graph", i.e. you're not starting with a given graph.  You're counting the number of trees on $10$ vertices satisfying a certain condition.

Comment: Hint: the sum of all the degrees is going to be $18$ (why?) and every other vertex has degree at least $1$. That doesn't leave you with much wiggle room!

Comment: @TheoBendit why is the sum of all degrees going to be 18?

Comment: Using the handshake theorem, and the fact that trees have one more vertex than edges, we'll have $9$ edges, for a sum of $18$ degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a vertex of degree 8:

[image]

This uses 9 of the 10 vertices. You need to add a tenth vertex in such a way that you still have a tree and you still have a vertex of degree 8. You also want to add labels to it.